# Identifying SMD IC on PCB

Tags: pcb, identification, dc-dc-converter

I have a faulty Control4 audio matrix PCB. I can't identify this item:

[image: pic1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely LT3580 in plastic DFN package.

According to data sheet, it has LCXY marking.